# How to convert Array 2D to Array collection in Flex

Tags: arrays, apache-flex, multidimensional-array, arraycollection

I have a 2D array as follows:

```
Asia  India  Chennai  TN  Category1 Product1 100
Asia  India  Mumbai   MH  Category1 Product1 100
Asia  India  Calcutta CT  Category1 Product1 100
Asia  India  Calcutta CT  Category2 Product2 200
EMEA  UK     London   LN  Category3 Product1 123    
EMEA  UK     London   LN  Category3 Product2 455    
EMEA  UK     Reading  RN  Category1 Product1 500    
EMEA  UK     Reading  RN  Category1 Product2 430
```

How can I convert the above 2D Array to Array collection so that I can access each data with individual attribute like the first column to indicate attribute as "continent",2nd column as "country" etc ., arrayCollection haveing the structure as {Continent:"Asia", Country:"India",...etc} and so on.How to achieve it dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private var a:Array=new Array([100,200,300,40],[252,25,25,32]);
private var a1:Array=new Array();
[Bindable]
private var ac:ArrayCollection=new ArrayCollection();
private function init():void
{
 for(var i:int=0;i<a.length;i++)
 {
  a1[i]=new Array()
  for(var j:int=0;j<a[i].length;j++)
  {
   a1[i]["col"+j]=a[i][j];
   }
 }
ac.source=a1;

ac.refresh()
Alert.show(ac.toString());
}
```